# Group by based on year in date from data table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an data table like this  (Payment month column as date)

```
PaymentMonth        Amount

01/01/2014           100

01/02/2014           200

01/03/2014           200

01/01/2015           300

01/02/2015           300

01/01/2016           200
```

I need output datatable as below (group by using year in paymentmonth column)

```
Year    Amount

2014     500

2015     600

2016     200
```

Get output datatable using linq or compute in c#

Thanks
M. Prabhu

Comment: What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(r => DateTime.Parse(r["PaymentMonth"].ToString()).Year)
                      .Select(x=> new { Year = x.Key, 
                                        Amount = x.Sum(r=>Int32.Parse(r["Amount"])
                                      }
                     ).OrderBy(x=>x.Year);
```

I suppose that `PaymentMonth` is a `DateTime` object and `data` is the collection that holds your data.

Comment: only one change  as    .GroupBy(r => DateTime.Parse(r["PaymentMonth"].ToString()).Year)

Answer (score 1):

As a learning exercise I have done it like below. I am new to LINQ so can't vouch whether this is most efficient way but nevertheless it works and is self explainaible.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PaymentMonth", typeof(System.DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), 100);
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2014, 2, 1), 200);
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2014, 3, 1), 200);
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), 300);
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), 300);
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), 200);

var sumResult = from amt in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group amt by amt.Field<System.DateTime>("PaymentMonth").Year into agg
                select new { Year=agg.Key,SumAmount=agg.Sum(r=>r.Field<int>("Amount")) };

DataTable dtAgg = new DataTable();
dtAgg.Columns.Add("Year",typeof(int));
dtAgg.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));

foreach(var item in sumResult)
{
   dtAgg.Rows.Add(item.Year, item.SumAmount);
}
```

DataTable dtAgg now contains aggregated data as below

```
Year    Amount

2014     500

2015     600

2016     200
```